# Possible to change font size of iOS select input using Ionic

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework

I have a project I am working on in Ionic and the client has asked if the font size can be reduced on the select inputs.

This is a random picture from Google, but shows the select 'scroller' on iOS that I am referencing:

[image]

The blue, green and red options are what need smaller font size. I'm pretty sure that it can't be done, easier for me too.

Answer (score 0):

You dont state which version of ionic you are using, so i will assume it is the latest version.

Each component in ionic has assigned sass variables which can be used to target the specific element of the component which can then be used to style it accordingly.

In your `theme/variables.scss` file you can target a variable which will then override the default style. In your case that would be the font size of the select. Now for this use case the font size is an inherited property and does not have a specific sass variable assigned to it ( you can view all the sass variables for the select [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/#sass-variables))

So in that case to override the default styles you have to explicitly wrap your scss code with

```
.ios,.md,.wp{
    // your style here
}
```

From your image it looks like you are using the "action sheet select" style. which would target `.action-sheet-ios .action-sheet-button` class to change the font size.

```
.ios{
    .action-sheet-ios .action-sheet-selected,
    .action-sheet-ios .action-sheet-button{
         font-size:1rem;
     }
}
```

This targets `ios` specifically.

Answer (score -1):

this can be done through css. first serve your app through the lab

```
ionic serve --lab
```

Than inspect element from chrome and select your text component and find its class. and Then you can add your custom CSS Styling.

Cheers :D